# Floating elements , text element that runs over many lines followed by date

Tags: css

I've got problem placing the date in the example right behind the text

```
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
    <div class="text">asfd asdf sa f dsafas asfd gfds gds g fdsgfds gdsf fds  s gfds fds g fds ggsfd dsfgfds fds fds fds ds  ds dgsd fgfs g a sf faa a DATE right after this --> </div>
    <div class="date">12/12/12</div>
</div>
<div class="tt">asdf asd fdsa fdsa sad fdsas  fa fa f fda fda</div>
```

​

```
.content {
 display: block
}

.header, .tt {
 float: left;
}

 .header { 
 width: 100%;            
 }

.text {
 background: red;     
}

.date {
   background: blue;            
 }
```

please see the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/HpC9p/5/

I wan't the blue date to follow right after the text, regardless of number of lines

Comment: Do you want to achieve [this effect](http://jsfiddle.net/HpC9p/6/)? Otherwise, if you want to have it directly after the actual text, do what [7th mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11758977/1139697).

Comment: In this case you can read my answer and it will work...

Comment: @7th Sorry , my bad! Had a span on the date that had the float: right. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome friend! Just notice that you don't really need a "div" tag for the date. Since you're moving the "date" inside another div, and probably inside a "p" tag, maybe you'll want to use another "inline" element to do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you move your "date" div  inside your "text" class and remove it's floating and set it to "display: inline"? It's so much easier!

This is what you'll have:

```
<div class="text">
    asfd asdf sa f dsafas asfd gfds gds g fdsgfds gdsf fds  s gfds fds g fds ggsfd dsfgfds fds fds fds ds  ds dgsd fgfs g a sf faa a DATE right after this -->
    <div class="date">12/12/12</div>
</div>
```

And for the CSS:

```
.date {
   background: blue;
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You also have to remove the floating of your date div. Since it will behave as an "inline" element, you don't need to float it anymore. edit: There you go!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `float: left;` on the wrong element, as the `.date` should appear right of the `.text`, not right of the `.header`.

So the `.text` need a `float: left;` and also a specified width to leave some room for the date.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HpC9p/8/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I wanted the date to appear right after the text without the "width" on the text area